# iPhone - how may I hide a view and let it's space be used by other views (like android visibility = GONE)

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, visibility, show-hide

Do you know a simple (or not simple) way to hide a view (or anything like a view) and let the other views of the screen use the place left blank ? And make the opposite when showing back that view. Something like Android Visibility = GONE for layers.

Thank you

Comment: You should post some code so as to know where exactly you want to use that functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many UIKit classes have a property `hidden` that does what you want. It is defined in UIView so you will find it in most visual elements you use.

Comment: For what I've seen, hidden just hide the view and does not make the other views use the space left blank.

Comment: If you want to just see views behind the hidden one, this will do it. Another way to do it would be to send the view to the back of the view hierarchy with opaque views above it. If you actually want to have the views resize and tile themselves to fit some area of screen you could signal that to your view class many ways, but to do the resizing you would need to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as Visibility.GONE, as far as my research has shown, not even AutoLayout can help you. You have to manually replace the views affected by the optionally shown component (in my case, all the views below the optionalView on bottomView):

```
- (IBAction)toggleOptionalView:(id)sender {
    if (!_expanded) {
        self.optionalView.frame = CGRectMake(self.optionalView.frame.origin.x, self.optionalView.frame.origin.y, self.optionalView.frame.size.width, _optionalHeight);
        self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(self.bottomView.frame.origin.x, self.bottomView.frame.origin.y+_optionalHeight, self.bottomView.frame.size.width, self.bottomView.frame.size.height);
        _expanded = YES;
    } else {
        self.optionalView.frame = CGRectMake(self.optionalView.frame.origin.x, self.optionalView.frame.origin.y, self.optionalView.frame.size.width, 0);
        self.bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(self.bottomView.frame.origin.x, self.bottomView.frame.origin.y-_optionalHeight, self.bottomView.frame.size.width, self.bottomView.frame.size.height);
        _expanded = NO;

    }
}
```

It is advisable not to hard-code the height of the optional component, otherwise your code breaks every time you edit the XIB/Storyboard. I have a field float _optionalHeight which I set in viewDidLoad, so it is always up to date.